# Android : FileNotFoundException when trying to get an image from Uri

Tags: java, android, bitmap, uri, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to get an image's width and height in order to rezize it in case it is too big before showing it. My method receive an uri of the image but I always get a FileNotFoundException when trying to decode it using BitmapFactory.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
    Uri myUri;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(myUri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);

    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

Decode File returns throws a FileNotFoundException here. However, I can still show the image using the uri without using a bitmap factory using this :

```
        Uri myUri;

        Bitmap myBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), myUri);
```

The problem with this code is that the returned bitmap might cause an OutofMemoryError when using big images.

When I debug my Uri, I get this :

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A20472

UPDATE || Here is the working code

```
    Uri myUri;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    // This is the part that changed
    InputStream inputStream = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,new Rect(),options);

    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

All of this of course surrounded by try/catch.

Comment: It's been a while since I played with Android, but since it's a FileNotFoundException, have you tried checking "new File(myUri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath()" to see exactly what value that returns? There may be something weird going on there.

Comment: Need more information about myUri. I can't figure out what content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A20472 means in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `decodeStream` instead of `decodeFile`.

Open the stream with `getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri)`.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, Thank you. I have updated the question to give the resulting piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this for a while, I think the issue is probably that the image file really isn't there.

If you are attempting to access a local file on your computer, that file won't be in the Android sandbox where the app is actually running. You'll need to add it to the app as a resource, then access it as a resource instead of a file.

If you are attempting to access a web image, you need to download it first. The AbsolutePath of a web image 'http://example.com/example.jpg' would be '/example.jpg', which won't do you much good when you try to open it.

Comment: I am testing on an actual android device, not the sandbox.

To give more context, the user is asked to choose a picture from his device. In the method "onActivityResult" , which called after the user has selected his picture, the uri is created using the data in the Intent passed as parameter. The uri is defined like so :




    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Uri myUri= data.getData(); ... }